Growth of preimages of singular values of finite type entire map
Let $f\colon \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be an entire map having precisely two distinct singular values $w^1$ and $w^2$. If $w^i$ has infinitely many preimages under $f$, we write $(z_n^i)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} := f^{-1}(w^i)$, where we order points of the preimage so that the sequence $(|z_n^i|)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of absolute values is non-decreasing, i.e., $|z_{n + 1}^i| \geq |z_{n}^i|$ (and, of course, we suppose that they are all distinct: $z_n^i \neq z_m^i$ for $n \neq m$).
I am curious about various growth properties of the sequence $(z_n^i)$. In particular, I wonder if there exists $A > 0$ (depending on $f$) so that for $i = 1$ or $i = 2$ we have
$$
\frac{\log|z_{n + 1}^i|}{\log|z_{n}^i|} \leq A.
$$
Or, perhaps, there is a counterexample? And if it is so, then what conditions $f$ should satisfy so such constant $A$ exists? And of course, this question makes sense for any finite number of singular values...

You should never ask the same question here and on Mathoverflow simultaneously. You can ask in one place, wait a week and if you do not get a satisfactory answer then ask on the other site.
